# How to trigger Build/Rebuild/Clean in VS extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm developing a VS extension which related to the build/reabuild/clean of project. Does anyone know how to trigger the build/rebuild/clean action of a project by VSSDK?

Answer (score 4):

Need to use [DTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) implementation:

> The top-level object in the Visual Studio automation object model.
>   Refer to _DTE for this functionality. Do not instantiate from this
>   class.

---

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the field that
/// contain the AsyncPackage
/// instance.
/// </summary>
protected AsyncPackage AsyncPackage { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Represents the method that
/// retrieve the service with
/// the passed type.
/// </summary>
public async Task<T> GetServiceByTypeAsync<T>() where T : class
{
    return await AsyncPackage.GetServiceAsync(typeof(T)) as T;
}
```

Example of use:

```
Env.DTE dte = await GetServiceByTypeAsync<EnvDTE.DTE>()
```

And then you can get access to current solution and build configurations:

```
dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build();
dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Clean();

dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.BuildProject("Release", "UniqueName");
```

To find certain project:

```
foreach (Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
{
    dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.BuildProject("Release", project.UniqueName);
}
```

---

[_DTE Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) | [_Solution Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._solution?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) | [SolutionBuild Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.solutionbuild?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use DTE, use [IVsSolutionBuildManager.StartSimpleUpdateSolutionConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionbuildmanager.startsimpleupdatesolutionconfiguration?view=visualstudiosdk-2017).

For example, this will rebuild the solution

```
IVsSolutionBuildManager2 buildManager = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolutionBuildManager)) as IVsSolutionBuildManager2;
if (ErrorHandler.Failed(buildManager.StartSimpleUpdateSolutionConfiguration((uint)(VSSOLNBUILDUPDATEFLAGS.SBF_OPERATION_FORCE_UPDATE | VSSOLNBUILDUPDATEFLAGS.SBF_OPERATION_BUILD),
    (uint)VSSOLNBUILDQUERYRESULTS.VSSBQR_OUTOFDATE_QUERY_YES,
    0/*false*/)))
{
    //handle the error
}
```